# Is there a notion that $0 + \mathbb Ri$ or $\mathbb R + 0i$ has an 'internal complexification' equal to 'external complexification' of $\mathbb R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-geometry, almost-complex

I started studying the book of Daniel Huybrechts, Complex Geometry An Introduction. I tried studying [backwards](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13089/why-do-so-many-textbooks-have-so-much-technical-detail-and-so-little-enlightenme) as much as possible, but I have been stuck on the concepts of [almost complex structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure) and [complexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification). I have studied several books and articles on the matter including ones by [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), [Jordan Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf), [Gregory W. Moore](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/618Spring2019/GTLect2-LinearAlgebra-2019.pdf), [Steven Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285), [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834), [Gauthier](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319115108)

I have several questions on the concepts of almost complex structures and complexification. Here is one:

---

Note: For the question stated next, I mean 'internal' and 'external' as something like internal vs external direct sum. What I mean by 'internal' and 'external' complexification is not the same as in these articles: [Article 1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267168267_Complexifications_of_real_spaces_General_aspects), [Article 2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.09029.pdf), [Article 3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.07289.pdf)

In the articles, we have 'external complexification' as complexification like $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb C^2$ and 'internal complexification' as adding almost complex structures/complex structures like $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb C$.

---

**Question**: In [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), is there some kind of notion of 'internal' vs 'external' complexification, such that, for example, the 'internal' complexification of the $\mathbb R$-subspace $\mathbb R + 0i$ of $\mathbb C$ is actually 'literally' the same (and not merely $\mathbb C$-isomorphic) as the 'external' complexification of $\mathbb R$?

- Here, I mean 'literally' as with the following examples

  - Example 1: $GL(\mathbb R,n)$ is a set of matrices while $Aut(\mathbb R^n)$ is a set of maps so they are not 'literally' equal since they do not have the same underlying set.
  - Example 2: I consider $\mathbb R^{\mathbb C}$, $(\mathbb R^2,J)$ (see below) and $\mathbb C$ as literally equal to each other and literally unequal to $(\mathbb R^2,-J)$, even though they are all $\mathbb C$-isomorphic to each other.
- Below, I try to use the symbol '=' to denote what I believe are literal equalities (under certain conventions) and use the symbol '$\cong$' for isomorphisms.

**What I understand**:

1. It seems in [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) that the 'complexification' of $\mathbb R$ is, not merely $\mathbb C$-isomorphic, but actually literally the same as both of the 'complexifications' of the $\mathbb R$-subspaces $\mathbb R + 0i$ and $0 + \mathbb Ri$ of $\mathbb C$. (I kind of don't see $\mathbb R + 0i$ as literally the same thing as $\mathbb R$, but if you do, then you may focus on $0 + \mathbb Ri = \mathbb Ri$ instead of $\mathbb R + 0i$).
2. The complexification of $\mathbb R$ to be $\mathbb R^{\mathbb C} = \mathbb C = (\mathbb R^2,J)$, with $J:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, $J(u,v) := (-v,u)$, for $u,v \in \mathbb R$. Here, we have $\mathbb R^{\mathbb C}$'s underlying set ($\mathbb R^2$) to be a subset of the underlying set of $\mathbb C$ (which is also $\mathbb R^2$).
3. $(0 + \mathbb Ri)^{\mathbb C} = ((0 + \mathbb Ri)^2,K)$, with $K((0,vi),(0,wi)) := ((0,-wi),(0,vi))$. Here, we have $(0 + \mathbb Ri)^{\mathbb C}$'s underlying set as a subset of the underlying set of $\mathbb C^2$ (which is $\mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^4$, depending on convention).

**Here's my guess**: I kind of think the definition of internal complexification as that for $U$ an $\mathbb R$-subspace (or $(\mathbb R+0i)$-subspace) of a $\mathbb C$-vector space $W$, we have $U^{\text{internal}-\mathbb C} = W$ if and only if any of the following, which I think are equivalent

1. any $\mathbb R$-basis (or $(\mathbb R+0i)$-basis) of $U$ is a $\mathbb C$-basis of $W$
2. (for finite dimensions) $\dim_{\mathbb R} U = \dim_{\mathbb C} W$ and $\mathbb C$-span $U$ = $W$

   - I think of condition (1) as the generalisation of condition (2), similar to [this question I just posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518285/infinite-dimensional-vector-space-has-almost-complex-structure-if-and-only-if-it).
3. $iU := \{iu | u \in U\}$ is an $\mathbb R$-subspace of $W$ such that $U \cap iU = \{0_W\}$. Then $W_\mathbb R$ can be written as an internal direct sum $W_\mathbb R = U \bigoplus iU$, where $W_\mathbb R$ is $W$ treated as an $\mathbb R$-vector space.

I was also thinking something like if $U^{\text{internal}-\mathbb C} \ne W$, then at least $U^{\text{internal}-\mathbb C}$ is the unique $\mathbb C$-subspace of $W$ such that internally, $(U^{\text{internal}-\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R} = U \bigoplus iU$.

---

**Additional note based on the comments of [reuns](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/276986/reuns)**: I think that [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834), like [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), also have some notion of internal complexification.

In [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834), specifically [12.15 of Part I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAvYT.png), the authors seem to be talking about how complexification is or can be seen as (by some isomorphism I guess) a specific case of the more general notion of extension of scalars, as Wikipedia does. (Note: The authors don't introduce tensor products until 3 chapters later.)

The definition is that for $\mathcal K$ a subfield of a field $K$ and for a $\mathcal K$-vector space $L$, $L$ has extension $L^{K}$, a $K$-vector space given by formal linear combinations. The definition they gave is for finite $L$, but I believe the same idea works for infinite $L$. I believe the intended definition extended to allow for infinte-dimensional $L$ is as follows:

For $L$ with basis $E=\{e_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$

$$L = \{\sum_{j=0}^{n} b_j e_j | \text{for unique} \ b_j \in \mathcal K, e_j \in E, n \ge 0, j \in A \}$$

$$L^{K} := \{\sum_{j=0}^{n} a_j e_j | \text{for unique} \ a_j \in K, e_j \in E, n \ge 0, j \in A \}$$

Applied to $\mathcal K = \mathbb R$ and $K = \mathbb C$ (treating $\mathbb R$ as identical to $\mathbb R + 0i$), it seems then that this generalisation is what one (or maybe just 'I' instead of 'one') might call internal rather than external complexification.

---

Reason this could be important and is not some nitpicking that is resolved with 'up to isomorphism':

If both $\overline {\mathbb C}$ and $\mathbb C$ have $\mathbb R$-form $0 + i\mathbb R$, but $0 + i\mathbb R$'s (internal) complexification is $\mathbb C$, then it seems $\overline {\mathbb C}$ is never the literal (internal or external) complexification of any $\mathbb R$-vector space. (Of course, this may depend on your [definition of complexification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518259/nonstandard-definitions-of-complexifications), and I do kind of assume that the '$0 + i\mathbb R$' $\subseteq \mathbb C$ is the same as the '$0 + i\mathbb R$' $\subseteq \overline{\mathbb C}$.) However, that $\overline{\mathbb C}$ has conjugations but has no $\mathbb R$-forms seems to contradict [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 4.11.

Comment: I think there is a [problem p.8](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), with $W$ a real subspace of a complex vector space $V$ then the complexification of $W$ is never $V$. He meant $\dim_\Bbb{R}(W)=\dim_\Bbb{C}(V)$ and $\Bbb{C}W=V$. A complex vector space is a real vector space together with a $\Bbb{R}$-linear operator $I$ satisfying $I^2=-1$, so that we have $\Bbb{C}$-action $(a+ib).v=av+b I(v)$, it is the knowledge of this action that we call "complex vector space", thus there are often several different complex vector space structures.

Comment: @reuns Thanks. What is '$\mathbb C W$' ? Also about a real subspace $V$ of $W$ never having its complexification as $W$, right so, this is what makes me think of $W$ as a different kind of complexification of $V$. I mean, $(\mathbb Ri)^{\mathbb C}$ is indeed $\cong$ even though not equal to $(\mathbb R)^{\mathbb C}$. As I mentioned in my guess above, I do think $\dim W = \dim V$ (Condition 2) is I think a way to rectify the problem in p.8 for finite dimensional $V$ and $W$, but for infinite dimensional $W$ and $V$, is the analogue of Condition 2 indeed Condition 1?

Comment: $\Bbb{C}W=\{ zw\in V,z\in \Bbb{C},w\in W\}$. And on a real vector space there are only complex structures, no almost complex structure (which is when we try to glue together some complex structures on a bunch of tangent spaces to obtain a complex structure on a real manifold, for example the complex structure on the sphere $S^2\subset \Bbb{R}^3$ makes it isomorphic to the Riemann sphere $\Bbb{C}\cup\infty$, and the "almost complex structure problem" is to define such a global complex structure by some local constraints).

Comment: @reuns Thanks! about almost complex structures: in the book of Daniel Huybrechts, Complex Geometry An Introduction, for vector space $V$, an almost complex structure is defined as $J: V \to V$ and a complex structure is defined as $s_V^{\#}: \mathbb C \times V \to V$. Of course, there are bijections between the two notions, proving that they are equivalent notions for $\mathbb R$-vector spaces. I think it's just convention. I know for vector spaces wikipedia just says '[linear complex structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure)'

Comment: @reuns So, $\mathbb C W = \mathbb C-span W$?

Comment: @reuns About $\mathbb C W$, Question 1. Is my proposed definition of internal complexification of $W$ in $V$, which is the unique subspace $X$ of $V$ such that internally $X_{\mathbb R} = W \bigoplus Wi$, equivalent to what Conrad might have meant which is $\mathbb C W$ and $\dim W = \dim V$?

Comment: @reuns About $\mathbb C W$, Question 2. Is '$\dim W = \dim V$ and $V = \mathbb C W$' equivalent to 'any $\mathbb R$-basis of $V$ is a $\mathbb C$-basis of $W$' ?

Comment: @reuns About $\mathbb C W$, Question 3. In [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin 12.15 of Part I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAvYT.png), the authors seem to be talking about how complexification is or can be seen as (by some isomorphism I guess) a specific case of the more general notion of extension of scalars, as Wikipedia does. Is this then actually a generalisation of what one (or maybe just 'I' instead of 'one') might call internal rather than external complexification? (Note: i'm going to edit my question to include this)

Comment: @reuns I added a bounty to this question.

Comment: @reuns Never mind I figured it out. (see my answer below, if you want) You can answer if you want and then I'll award bounty to you I guess.

Comment: @reuns new question: [When or only when a complex vector space is the external complexification of a real vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527949/when-or-only-when-a-complex-vector-space-is-the-external-complexification-of-a-r)

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

---

First thing:

[Conrad actually gives the definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDEQ8.png), of $\mathbb C$-vector space $V$ as the internal complexification of $\mathbb R$-subspace $W$ of $W$, just before Theorem 3.2 as $V=W + iW$ and $W \cap iW = 0$, which I think is equivalent to saying $V_{\mathbb R} = W \bigoplus iW$ I just wish 2 things.

1. That this definition was more explicit. Perhaps as something like

> **Definition 3.2** We say that $V$ is the *internal complexification*, or just *complexification* if the context is clear, of $W$ if $V=W + iW$ and $W \cap iW = 0$

2. That we could define internal complexifications of any $\mathbb R$-subspace $W$ of $V$ as something like $W \bigoplus iW$ or like $\mathbb C$-span$(W)$. In this case of $W \bigoplus iW$, I think we would have to restrict to considering $\mathbb R$-subspaces such that $W \cap iW = 0$, thus excluding $W = V_{\mathbb R}$

---

Second thing: The unresolved issue is whether or not Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin has implicit notion for internal complexification such that it is internal and not external complexification that gets generalised by 12.15 of Part I (and 12.4 of Part I).