# Is disjoint union of discrete spaces is discrete?

Tags: general-topology

I mean internal, literal and external as in here: [Is there a notion that $0 + \mathbb Ri$ or $\mathbb R + 0i$ has an 'internal complexification' equal to 'external complexification' of $\mathbb R$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518339/is-there-a-notion-that-0-mathbb-ri-or-mathbb-r-0i-has-an-internal-com)

---

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology)#Preservation_of_topological_properties), 'every disjoint union of discrete spaces is discrete'. This refers to 'external' disjoint unions like the disjoint union of topological spaces without (necessarily) some common ambient topological space.

2 questions:

1. For 'internal' but not 'literal' disjoint unions:

Let $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ now be topological spaces that are topological subspaces of a common ambient topological space $S$. Then disjoint union is the subset of $S \times I$ given by $A := \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \times \{i\}$. I've seen this definition in geometry/topology texts where $I$ is actually a manifold such that $I$ has a topological structure.

For all $A_i$ discrete, what conditions (eg on cardinality or topology of $I$, or topology of $S$) make $A$ discrete?

2. For 'internal' and 'literal' disjoint unions:

Consider $S$ as the 'literal' and 'internal' union of $S = \bigcup_{i \in I} \{A_i\}$ of disjoint subspaces. (Disjoint is the original definition that each pair is disjoint: $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$.)

For all $A_i$ discrete, what conditions (eg on cardinality or topology of $I$, or topology of $S$) make $S$ discrete?

- Context for Question 2: I notice that for non-constant holomorphic map of connected Riemann surfaces $F: X \to Y$ ($X$ and $Y$ need not be compact, and $F$ need not be surjective), that $F$ is 'discrete' meaning that each fibre of $F$ is discrete. In this case,

$$X = \bigcup_{y \in Y} F^{-1}(y),$$

such that $X$ is a 'disjoint union' of discrete subspaces. However, this is not quite the same 'disjoint union' as talked about in wiki.

Comment: If I understand you ask if the union of disjoint discrete subsets of a topological space is discrete? If so, the answer is no : $\mathbb{R} = \cup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \{x\}$ is a union of disjoint discrete subspaces.

Comment: This might be a trivial observation, but the "external" case is equivalent to the "internal" one when the index set $I$ is given the discrete topology. It seems that things break down very easily if $I$ is given a coarser topology.

Comment: @DIdier Thanks! you may post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by disjoint union of topological spaces, you are talking about the union of disjoint subsets of a topological space, the answer is no. Here is a counter example.

In $\mathbb{R}$, with the usual topology, every singleton $\{x\}$ is discrete, but $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\{x\}$ is not discrete.

Comment: Doesn't directly answer my literal questions but directly answers what implicit and primary question about internal disjoint unions (thus i said DIdier_ may post as answer). thanks!